# Javascript warning with ui:inputSelect

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

A ui:inputSelect component is generating this javascript warning in the browser console when I invoke the change event.  I get the warning multiple times once for each item in the list.

> WARNING: AttributeSet.set(): unable to override the value for 'value=function (cmp, fn) { return fn.empty(cmp.get("v.exhibitPublicName")); }'. FunctionCallValues declared in markup are constant.

Here is the code for the input:

```
<ui:inputSelect class="slds-select" label="Exhibition:" labelClass="slds-form-element__label" aura:id="exhibits" change="{!c.exhibitChange}" >
    <ui:inputSelectOption text="" label="All Exhibits" value="{!empty(v.exhibitPublicName)}"/>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.exhibits}" var="exhibit">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!exhibit.Public_Exhibit_Name__c}" label="{!exhibit.Public_Exhibit_Name__c}"  value="{! v.exhibitPublicName == exhibit.Public_Exhibit_Name__c}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

The handler does't even have anything in it:

```
exhibitChange:function(component, event, helper) {

}
```

Any ideas on what is causing the warning.  I am just trying to fill the dropdown, and set the selected value if it matches an attribute.

Thanks!

Comment: To invoke a controller action, you need to have expression statement :`{!c.methodName}` format.So change attribute should be equal to `{!c.exhibitChange}` instead of `c.exhibitChange`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Praveen  The code is working.  It was actually working before I put the event handler into the expression syntax.    I am still getting the warning.  Any other ideas?  I am getting the warning multiple times once for each item in the list.

Comment: does the `<aura:attribute name="exhibitPublicName"/>` have access attribute specified?if not set the access to `public` like this :  `<aura:attribute name="exhibitPublicName" access="public"/>`

Comment: The access was not specified, I did try to change it to public as you suggested but the warning is still there.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong here.Can you try removing this line : `value="{! v.exhibitPublicName == exhibit.Public_Exhibit_Name__c}"` in the `ui:inputSelectOption`  and have an value attribute for the `ui:inputSelect`:`<ui:inputSelect value="{!v.exhibitPublicName}"/>`

Comment: Intesting: It looks like `value="{!empty(v.exhibitPublicName)}"` expands to this:  `value=function (cmp, fn) { return fn.empty(cmp.get("v.exhibitPublicName")); }`. I think that's where the error is.

Comment: @Praveen That was it.  The dropdown has a value, and the items also have a value.  The documentation says that the items value sets the selected state of the option, but maybe that is only used in the case of a muli-select scenario.  Thank you so much.  Please submit your solution as the answer and I will mark it so it will help others.

Comment: @ChrisMullins Glad it worked.I have add the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke a controller action, you need to have expression statement :`{!c.methodName}` format.So change attribute should be equal to `{!c.exhibitChange}`instead of `c.exhibitChange`.

Also remove this line :
 `value="{! v.exhibitPublicName == exhibit.Public_Exhibit_Name__c}"` from
 `ui:inputSelectOption` and have an value attribute for the `ui:inputSelect:<ui:inputSelect value="{!v.exhibitPublicName}"/>`

Like this:

```
<ui:inputSelect value="{!v.exhibitPublicName}" class="slds-select" label="Exhibition:" labelClass="slds-form-element__label" aura:id="exhibits" change="{!c.exhibitChange}" >
    <ui:inputSelectOption text="" label="All Exhibits" />
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.exhibits}" var="exhibit">
        <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!exhibit.Public_Exhibit_Name__c}" label="{!exhibit.Public_Exhibit_Name__c}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

Comment: Just a follow up to using this ui:inputSelect sucessfully. I ended up not binding the value declaratively at all.  The problem I ended up having is that the inital value would never set correctly if I wanted to default the parameter, or pass in via a query string.  So I would recommend not using the value attribute declaritively at all, and just set in your init code like 

component.find("exhibitSelect").set("v.value", component.get("v.exhibitPublicName"));